# Spring-Oauth Google configuratiion

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-sheets, google-oauth

I have made a project where i can fetch the google sheets data using java.
All the things are working fine.

1] Except GoogleCredential() is showing deprecated. I searched for the solution everywhere it shows to use [Google Auth Library for Java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java) but i am not able to understand how would i use this in my code.

2] Also, how can i restrict the google from asking consent to email scope profile everytime the user logs in using google oauth2.

Thanks in advance for help..

```
private Sheets getClient() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        Credential credential = new GoogleCredential().toBuilder()
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
                .build()
                .setAccessToken(tokenUtil.getAccessToken())
                .setRefreshToken(tokenUtil.getRefreshToken());
        return new Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("GoogleSheetsApiIntegration").build();
    }
```

I have tried below method using credential.json approach and it was working fine but i want to authenticate each user and every user should use different token generated by loging in from thier own account.

```
private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT)
      throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = AdminSDKResellerQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    if (in == null) {
      throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    }
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
        GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
        .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
        .setAccessType("offline")
        .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
  }
```